# pyqt5 tablewidgets retrieving data

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

Hello i want to retrieve data from mysql database and i want to add that in my pyqt5 tablewidget but it is giving me error that int object is not iterable

this is my code

```
def LoadData(self):
    conn = mdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "pyqt5")

    with conn:
        query = "SELECT * FROM data"
        cur = conn.cursor()
        result = cur.execute(query)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate():
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, col_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

Comment: Please provide error message in details. Are you facing as issue with this line? for row_number, row_data in enumerate():

Comment: the error is for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
TypeError: int object is not iterable

Comment: @Parwiz. Do you ever bother reading documentation or tutorials? If you did, you'd see that the [Cursor.execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) method clearly does not return a result-set. Please do some basic research before posting questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you are missing "enumerate(result)" into first for loop.

```
 def LoadData(self):
    conn = mdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "pyqt5")

    with conn:
        query = "SELECT * FROM data"
        cur = conn.cursor()
        result = cur.execute(query)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, col_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

Comment: yea i have give the result in the loop but the same problem     it is telling for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
TypeError: int object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but you need to make a few edits:
cur = execute(query)
result= cur.fetchall()

def LoadData(self):

```
conn = mdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "pyqt5")
with conn:
    query = "SELECT * FROM data"
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
    for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, col_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```